# One Google Adsense account: two diverse websites. How to combine?

Tags: google, web-development, google-adsense, google-adsense-policies

I have read a lot about it, but most of them are outdated so that's why I am going to ask it here.

**I have two websites:**

- Website about politics
- Website about sports

They have nothing in common, at all, yet **I have just one Google Adsense account and I'd like to use this account to make ads for them**.

My question is: is this even possible? Can I use my Google Adsense code for both of the websites? Let's say I have created an ad unit: can I just use this exact same piece of code *(so the exact same ad)* on both of the websites?

In other words: what should I do to achieve what I want? The reason I am asking this, is because I want to avoid being blocked by Google.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you are allowed to use the same account for various websites. I found the following discussion in which the question was raised with tech support by doing a Google search. Read more here: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/adsense/1B-ybuj0y9k/RQCzy7gST74J

Comment: This one is outdated. It's from 7 years ago... could you provide a newer one?

Comment: From 2015: http://ask.shoutmeloud.com/t/is-it-advisable-to-use-one-adsense-account-for-multiple-websites/821